# Tomcat jdbc pool shows ClassNotFoundException but works

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, classloader, jdbc-pool

To configure a JDBC pool for Microsoft SQLServer in Tomcat 9 I've added below to `server.xml`

```xml
<Resource auth="Container" 
   type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
   factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer" 
   maxActive="100" maxIdle="30"  maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/SABA" 
   defaultAutoCommit="true" 
   username="user" password="pass" url="jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:1433;DatabaseName=mydb;" />
```

During tomcat startup I get lots of `ClassNotFoundException`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

This is obviously normal as I did not copy the SQL Server drivers into Tomcat libs, but after application startup, the pool is working and I can get connection from it. I have the SQL Server drivers in my application `WEB-INF\lib`.

Is it a default behavior? If this is normal, can I suppress the exception during Tomcat startup?

Comment: What happens if you remove the driverClassName from the config? It sounds like that might be an incorrect FQCN but the correct one is being loaded and registers itself correctly

Comment: I get `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://...`

Comment: There is another driver loaded or another driver configuration there. It could be on your PATH or in an OS startup config for another jdbc. Either way that config cannot find the one relative named to it.

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using `jdbc/SABA` in your web-app? I would sooner guess that your application is creating connections with `DriverManager` or a data source created within your application instead of the one provided by Tomcat.

Comment: Dear @MarkRotteveel to test is when i change `name="jdbc/BadName` to something else I get `Name [SABA] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [SABA].` Also I dig to code an find that the connection is get from the pool

Comment: Hmm, curious, I guess that means the Tomcat data source starts to work as soon as the driver is available from your web app, though that will likely cause a memory leak if your web-app is unloaded or redeployed without restarting Tomcat.

Comment: I think the error happens because the Resource element is on server.xml. Exceptions should go away if it's moved to the app's META-INF/context.xml